# Cardio, lifting, Cardio

Tags: cardio, powerlifting

```
I am 190cm tall, 96KG weight.
```

My diet: Breakfast: 2 boiled Eggs.

lunch: chicken breast, 1/2 of cup white rice.

No dinner, or snacks but sometimes i take: small chocolate bar (Kinder).

My Gym schedule for the past 1 week:

```
20 min Cardio  burns about : 350 cals. 

full body cycle lifting mainly upper-body lifting. 

30 min Cardio on treadmill burns about : 270 cals.
```

I do take supplements: Whey 100% protein about 50grams a day.

and 2 bills of `Amino Acids 2222 tablets .`

Is this schedule good to lose fats and gain muscles ?

Note: i use my `fitnesspal` application and most of the days it says that i am not taking enough cals.

Whats the best i can do at this point.

i currently consume about 650 calories a day,

55% carbs, 30% protein, 15% fats.

i burn in total of 650 cardio and about 300 lifting, ( i am not 100% sure about lifting o how much i burn)

Comment: I'm less worried about calories, and more worried about whether you're getting all your vitamins and minerals, given that you eat the same things every day. A diet should be extremely varied, and include all kinds of foods.

Comment: sometimes i eat an apple or a banana between breakfast and lunch,

Comment: That doesn't address the problem at all though. I would advise that you don't try to create your own meal plan, and instead consult with a professional about it.

Comment: we dont have professional consult around here :( @Alec and if there was it would cost me around 200$ for just those tips

Comment: anywhere i can look for a tip like this a website or something ? \

Comment: Read this https://btn.academy/blog/why-is-nutrition-so-complicated/, particularly tips 4 - 9. Just to second what @Alec said, if that's all you eat, you're missing out on the majority of vitamins and minerals your body needs.

Comment: Could you please put a summary of the total calories, carbs, fats, proteins you eat per day?  And the total calories you burn in a day by working out (including the weight lifting)?  Additionally, these are also critical:  you age, your detailed weight-lifting routine (including number of sets, resting period between the sets, weights lifted in each set, whether the last rep in a set is also your failure rep).  Only after this info, I'll be confident enough to judge whether your routine/diet combo is good for which purpose.  Else, it is just too hard to give any reliable answer.

Comment: 650 kcal/day is starvation. No, this is not a good way to lose fat or gain muscle.

Comment: how much should i go for :/ i can't eat sugar stuff, any recommendations ?

Answer (score 3):

The basic answer is no, your current routine is not best suited for losing fat and gaining muscle. (There are already several questions on the site geared toward this, so when you have the time, read through all of the questions and answers that [are already on the site](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=lose%20fat%20gain%20muscle%20is%3Aquestion)).

To get an idea of your actual needs, first you need to know your basal metabolic rate (BMR). This is simply how much energy you need to exist each day, not counting any activity. There are [online calculators for that](http://www.bmi-calculator.net/bmr-calculator/metric-bmr-calculator.php), and there are calculators for [total daily energy expenditure](https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/calculate-your-total-daily-energy-expenditure-tdee.html) (TDEE), which attempts to account for activity as well. There are several different equations for TDEE, that one uses Mifflin St. Jeour.

To be as accurate as you can be, I would do a BMR calculation, and then find weight based calorie counts for all daily activities and add that up. Find calculators for the various equations variants for BMR (Such as [this one that allows selection](https://www.freedieting.com/calorie-calculator)) and average them all out. That will be the closest you can come without a lab to how many calories you need to eat a day to maintain weight.

Once you know that, you can use a [meal planner such as this one](https://www.mydietmealplan.com/meal-plan-generator/) to generate your meal plans. Ignore anyone that says "3500 calories = 1 lb lost", as that is a myth. As long as you are burning more calories than you eat, you will lose weight.

That should help you with eating and meal planning. As has been noted in the comments, yes, you may lose weight on your current plan, but you are almost guaranteed to develop vitamin deficiencies and other medical problems if you follow your current diet long term.

As far as your fitness goes, it also appears very limited, and doesn't really show a plan. Decide what your main focus is, and gear all your workouts towards that. Pause and reassess every few months to gauge success, interest and enjoyment in what you are doing. The site has many good answers already about fitness plans for various goals, but you can always ask about your current plan as well. Just be as detailed as possible, so that the people potentially answering for you won't have to ask for clarifications.

If you want to really be serious about it, maintain a daily activity and food log. Write down everything you eat/do. Data is valuable, and the more you can collect the better, and the more detailed you are, the better. Otherwise you may gain or lose weight, and have no idea why.